# Can't view table in parent page but single page it's working

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table

I'm doing a school system whereby a parent can view their children score. but the problem is, I can't view the table score for parent to view their children score in the system. the page can be view smoothly as admin and as single page (parent_view_score.php) works fine. I don't know what is the problem because I've been debug the page and it's weird that it's not showing the table in the system.

the only different with admin_view_score page, admin can add, edit and delete the score. while parent can only view their kids score.

I think it's maybe the problem with the tag page but I can't find the error in the codes.

The table won't show in `parent.php?tag=parent_view_scores`

but if `parent_view_scores.php` will show the table and data correctly.

```
<?php
session_start();
require("connect.php");
?>    
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style_view.css" />
    <title>My PIBG</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="style_div" >
    <form method="post">
    <table width="755">
        <tr>
            <td width="190px" style="font-size:18px; color:#006; text-indent:30px;">View Scores</td>

        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    </div> 
    <br />

    <div id="content-input">
    <form method="post">
         <table border="1" width="1050px" align="center" cellpadding="3" class="mytable" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <th>No</th>
                <th>Students Name</th>
                <th>Class Name</th>
                <th>Subject Name </th>
                <th>MidTerm</th>
                <th>Final</th>
                <th>Note</th>

            </tr>
             <?php
        $sql_sel=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT A.stu_name, A.class_name, sub_name, midterm, final, note FROM stu_score_tbl A, stu_tbl B, users_tbl C WHERE A.stu_name = B.stu_name AND B.parent_ic = C.icnum AND C.username = '{$_SESSION['username']}'");
        if($sql_sel === FALSE) { 
        die('could not get data'.mysql_error()); }

        $i=0;
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql_sel)){
        $i++;
        $color=($i%2==0)?"lightblue":"white";
        ?>
          <tr bgcolor="<?php echo $color?>">
                <td><?php echo $i;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['stu_name'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['class_name'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['sub_name'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['midterm'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['final'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['note'];?></td>
               </tr>
        <?php
        }
        ?>

    </table>
    </form>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: how do you connect to the DB with this page, can't see include or connect ? mysql is deprecated and unsafe and you should look into mysqli or PHP PDO for security.

Comment: i used connect.php <?php
session_start();
require("connect.php");
?>

Comment: my connect.php <?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("No Connection");
mysql_select_db("mypibg") or die("No Database name");
?>

Comment: either I am going totally blind or you've missed the connect code in the script above.

Comment: also dont forget to sanitize (mysql_real_escape_string) your input values to your sql string. Ideally try not to use mysql_* functions and use PDO.

Comment: So, is this code from parent.php? Where is the $_GET['tag'] check where it's saying to load this code? Appart from that, are you sure that $_SESSION['username'] contains the correct value? Also, as said by others, please, use MySQLi or PDO drivers, and sanitize the query.

Comment: i didnt know how to use MySQLi or PDO yet. :(

Comment: @Razican yes the session is correct because i can view the data/query for the sql in a table if only i view the page only.